# How does VS2012 Map IIS Express Site Name?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

While upgrading from MVC 4 Beta to MVC 4 RC, I ran my baseline built against the Beta release and a branch built against the RC concurrently to do a side-by-side comparison.

As a result, IIS Express ended up with two sites, `MyProject` and `MyProject (1)`.  I have now merged the RC branch, which IIS Express knows as `MyProject (1)`.  It's slightly annoying to have the `(1)` appended, so I thought I would just edit `applicationhost.config` to remove the original `MyProject` entry and rename `Myproject (1)` to `Myproject`.

As a result, VS2012 can no longer start that project.  If I reverse the rename, it works again.

There must be an association between the project and the IIS Express site name that still calls the project `MyProject (1)`, but I cannot find where that association is kept.  I have searched MyProject.csproj and MyProject.csproj.user.

Where is the association between the Visual Studio project and the IIS Express site name kept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you oped your visual studio project `projectname.csproj` with a text editor (another solution is to right-click the project and unload it "Unload Project", then menu "Edit projectname.csproj") you can find a section `ProjectExtensions` where you can find the mapping:

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>6213</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:6189/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Note `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` and `<IISUrl>http://localhost:6189/</IISUrl>`.

You can find the IIS port (6189) in you IIS Express config file `applicationhost.config`.

```
<sites>
    <site name="MyApplication.Web" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\MyApplication.Web" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6189:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
        ...
</sites>
```

What I would suggest is to go back to Visual Studio Development Server from the menu and remove the section in your IIS config file.
Now in Visual Studio you can remap IIS Express.